# How can I launch programmatically (C++) an application from a Windows shortcut (.lnk file)?

Tags: c++, windows, shortcut, lnk

how can I launch programmatically an application from a Windows shortcut (.lnk file)?

I tried to use the API ShellExecute and it seems to work. Any caveat?

Thank you.

Here it is a snippet of my current code:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main( int, char** )
{
   std::map< int, std::wstring > errors;
   errors[0]                      = L"The operating system is out of memory or resources.";
   errors[ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]   = L"The specified file was not found."; 
   errors[ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]   = L"The specified path was not found."; 
   errors[ERROR_BAD_FORMAT]       = L"The .exe file is invalid (non-Microsoft Win32 .exe or error in .exe image).";
   errors[SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED]    = L"The operating system denied access to the specified file.";
   errors[SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE] = L"The file name association is incomplete or invalid.";
   errors[SE_ERR_DDEBUSY]         = L"The Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE) transaction could not be completed because other DDE transactions were being processed.";
   errors[SE_ERR_DDEFAIL]         = L"The DDE transaction failed.";
   errors[SE_ERR_DDETIMEOUT]      = L"The DDE transaction could not be completed because the request timed out.";
   errors[SE_ERR_DLLNOTFOUND]     = L"The specified DLL was not found.";
   errors[SE_ERR_FNF]             = L"The specified file was not found.";
   errors[SE_ERR_NOASSOC]         = L"There is no application associated with the given file name extension. This error will also be returned if you attempt to print a file that is not printable.";
   errors[SE_ERR_OOM]             = L"There was not enough memory to complete the operation.";
   errors[SE_ERR_PNF]             = L"The specified path was not found.";
   errors[SE_ERR_SHARE]           = L"A sharing violation occurred.";

   int ret = reinterpret_cast< int >( ::ShellExecute(0,L"open",L"\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Accessories\\Calculator.lnk\"",0,0,SW_SHOW) );
   const int minimumRetOK = 33;
   if ( ret < minimumRetOK ) {
      if ( errors.count( ret ) ) {
         std::wcout << L"Error " << ret << L" " << errors[ ret ];
      } else {
         std::wcout << L"Error " << ret << L" undocumented error";
      }
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are uncertain about, the behaviour you observe is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The ShellExecute  "open" operation, will do whatever the shell does when you "open" the file referenced by the file argument (you can right-click a shortcut and select "Open" explicitly, but that is also the default operation for .lnk, so is the same as a double-click).

"Opening" a short-cut file it will "open" the target, if the target is an executable it will run, if it is a document or data file, it will open in the associated program, or prompt for a program if none associated.

Answer (score 2):

`ShellExecute` or `CreateProcess` should be able to open link file. If they can't find the associated file and/or the program, you can always use those API and delegate the hard work to "cmd start" or "explorer". E.g. `ShellExecute(0, "open", "explorer", linkfile, 0, SW_SHOW);`

Comment: I always thought ``CreateProcess`` was unable to open link files (only executables), for these you need the Shell (e.g. ``ShellExecute``)

Answer (score 1):

`ShellExecute` should work.

But, ...

```
int main( int, wchar_t* )
```

... no compiler I know of supports this signature. Just write:

```
int main()
```

Also, for the dignostic messages, just use the `FormatMessage` Windows API function, or, if the code is exclusively for Visual C++, use the appropriate support class that's bundled with that compiler.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in the main signature. Microsoft compiler allows me to do so :-)

Regarding FormatMessage, I am aware of it but I think in this case it will not work because ShellExecute has its particular error codes.

Comment: @uvts_cvs: well, i can't find any message resource DLL for shell32, so `FormatMessage` would only work for the three `ERROR_`*xxx* codes. :-(